# Save to album in unity3d project

Tags: c#, path, unity-game-engine

I have a button in my scene named "Save to Album".

By clicking on it i need to save screenshot to album in device.

Using

```
Application.CaptureScreenshot
```

i got screen shot.

But i have to save to "Gallery" in both android and ios device. How can i do ?

I need good suggestions and help.

Comment: What device? What "gallery"?

Comment: yes to device gallery

Comment: The Prime31 etcetera plugins for iOS and Android have this functionality. Unless you're comfortable writing native plugins for both platforms, I'd check that out.